# Rust reading a file

Tags: file, io, compiler-errors, rust

I'm trying to read a file named `enable.txt` that's in the same dir as my `main.rs`, and my code looks like this:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;
use std::error::Error;
fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("enable.txt");
    let display = path.display();
    let mut file = File::open(&path);
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents);
    println!("{}", contents);
}
```

When I compile it with either `cargo run` or `rustc src/main.rs`, I get this error message:

```
error: no method named `read_to_string` found for type `std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:10:10
   |
10 |     file.read_to_string(&mut contents);
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: In the future, I'd encourage your to *search for your error message*. This **exact** issue was encountered and addressed by other people at least two years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `File::open()` returns a `std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>` which needs to be unwrapped in some way in order to access the file. The way I prefer to do this is to use `expect()` like this:

```
...
fn main() {
    ...
    let mut file = File::open(&path).expect("Error opening File");
    ...
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).expect("Unable to read to string");
    ...
}
```

This will either return the expected value or `panic` with the error message provided depending on if the operation was successful.

Comment: You can replace the calls to “expect” with a match expression or an “if let Ok(varname)” expression and manually handle the possible result variants. The code I have above is the quick and dirty way that punts all error handling my into a panic. It is not too hard to handle it manually though. You should be able to find an example of how to handle this Imari there here on stack overflow or in the rust “book”.

Comment: Also consider looking at the question that your question was marked as a duplicate of.